# how can i make Generic function's params as protobuffer in java?

Tags: java, generics, protocol-buffers, generic-programming

I want to make a function to handle different type of protocal buffer variable, which all need to call api function of protobuffer. code like this:

```
public <T > void Send(T s) {
    if (mode == "PUB") {
      sock.send(s.toByteArray(), 0);   // error here, toByteArray is an api function in protocal buffer
    } else if (mode == "REQ") {
      sock.send(s.toByteArray(), 0); 
      byte[] rs = sock.recv(0);
      System.out.println("recv ack " + Arrays.toString(rs));
    } else {
      System.out.println("Unknown mode " + mode);
      System.exit(1);
    }   
  }

  public <T> void Recv(T t) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
    if (m_mode == "SUB") {
      t = T.parseFrom(m_sock.recv()); // error here
    } else if (m_mode == "REP") {
      T er = T.parseFrom(m_sock.recv());
      m_sock.send(er.getReqid());
      return er; 
    } else {
      System.out.println("Unknown mode " + m_mode);
      System.exit(1);
      return T.parseFrom(m_sock.recv());
    }   
  }
```

That didnt work for me, bc s.toByteArray() and T.parseFrom() is not found, can anyone help on this? 
I am a c++ developer, learning java recently, can java support generic function, and handle the generic params according to my function declaration?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just make `s` a byte instead?

Comment: Does it help if you compare your strings with `.equals` rather than `==`?  Or better still, use an `enum` for the mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your generated protobuf classes extend the type `com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage` and that type has the method `toByteArray` (which it inherited from `com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite`)

Just declare your method as :

```
public void Send(com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage s) {
```

or

```
public void Send(com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite s) {
```

You don't need generics - you can depend on the inheritance type hierarchy.

Also note: never compare Strings with `==` in Java like you are doing in your posted code. Use the `equals` method instead; `==` returns false if the Strings have the same content but are different instances of the `String` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erwin @Erwin Bolwidt , Can i ask one more question? for recv side, i need to call ParseFrom() method, com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage dont have it, how can i design the Recv side?

Comment: I'm not too deeply familiar with protobufs - my observations come from general Java knowledge and some googling for Javadocs. It looks like you need a way to get a `Parser` implementation for the particular class that you want to deserialize. If you want to be able to deserialize any object without knowing the type in advance, it seems you need to both write and read it as an `Any` object.

Comment: `com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage` does not have `ParseFrom()` because the binary data contains no information about the message it was generated from, only field numbers, types, and values. The concrete classes for each message type will have the method though, so `T.ParseFrom()` should work.